# xml file not found as a resource , check with the classpath

Tags: java, xml, batch-file, command-prompt

Hi i have two files in my conf folder and im supposed to use those files  in the java program and i **run** it using **batch file**, one Im able to pull it up using batch file, but with the other file(i.e for stconfig.xml), Im not able to do so as Im getting the following error

```
    "stconfig.xml not found as a resource, check the classpath",
```

my batchfile content is below:

```
    @echo off


    java    -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -classpath ./bin;./conf   com.mydomain.demoapp.DemoProgram
    pause
```

in my javacode, im referring the path of  xml as ****"/stconfig.xml"**** and this file is present in the conf folder. The other file which is getting pulled up by the batch file is stfile.properties , and in java code im referring its path as **"stfile"**

Thanks,
Balaji

Comment: Please show your code and file structure.

Comment: Hi BetaRide,thanks for the reply, I have added a bit of code

Comment: Your java code (where you are trying to open such files) would be interesting too.